# Every 7 or so toFixed(2) fails and returns a lot of decimals

Tags: javascript

Every seven for so incriments, my toFixed function returns a lot of decimals. It's tied to round so I thought I was safe.

The product starts at 49.97 and winds up at $349.78999999999996
 for 7 units. For 14 units: $699.5799999999999, 29 units: $1449.1299999999999. How can I fix this?

```
updateCart: function() {
                // if key exists
            if (storage.getItem('domehaOrder') != undefined) {
                //jQuery('.quantity').css('display', 'inline-block')
                //jQuery('.top-cart-item-image').css('display', 'block')

                //Get local storage order
                var order = storage.getItem('domehaOrder')

                //get local storage products


                // Parse existing order & products// local storage Must be string
                order = JSON.parse(order);
                console.log(order)

                //Get product data from spree backend
                storeobj = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('domehaProducts'));
                console.log("Store: " + JSON.stringify(storeobj))




            // Merge products and cart data
            var domecart = order.items.map(function(item) {
            merge = storeobj.products.filter(function(prod) {
                    return prod.id == item.productID;
                })[0];
                return Object.assign(item, { images: merge.image, name: merge.name, price: merge.display_price, intPrice: merge.price});
            });

            console.log("cart "+ JSON.stringify(domecart))
            //Grab Total
            var total = domecart.map(function(a) {return a.intPrice * a.quantity}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);



            var quantity = domecart.map(function(a) {return a.quantity}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            console.log(quantity)
            // Refactor for KO

            domecart = domecart.map(function(e) {
                return {
                    price: "$" + e.intPrice * e.quantity,
                    images: e.images,
                    name: e.name,
                    quantity: e.quantity,
                    id: e.productID
                }
            });

            console.log("domecart" + domecart)
            newcart = {
                items: domecart, 
                total: "$" + total,
                quantity: "x " + quantity,
            }
            console.log("final cart" + JSON.stringify(newcart))
            //// Bind to KO

            this.cart = newcart;

            //Strinify and save for later
            //domecart = JSON.stringify(newcart)
            //storage.setItem('domehaCart', domecart)

            }
        },
```

Comment: I notice you aren't using `.toFixed(2)` on the `domecart = ...` bit. Is this where you're seeing the issue? That aside, you should always work in pennies and only divide by 100 to show the value to the user at the very end.

Comment: If you copy this into an answer I will accept it. Thank you.